# send2cy doesn't work in Rstudio ~ Cyrest, Cyotoscape

Tags: r, cytoscape

When I run "send2cy" function in R studio, I got error.

```
# Basic setup
library(igraph)
library(RJSONIO)
library(httr)
dir <- "/currentdir/"
setwd(dir)
port.number = 1234
base.url = paste("http://localhost:", toString(port.number), "/v1", sep="")
print(base.url)

# Load list of edges as Data Frame
network.df <- read.table("./data/eco_EM+TCA.txt")

# Convert it into igraph object
network <- graph.data.frame(network.df,directed=T)

# Remove duplicate edges & loops
g.tca <- simplify(network, remove.multiple=T, remove.loops=T)

# Name it
g.tca$name = "Ecoli TCA Cycle"

# This function will be published as a part of utility package, but not ready yet.
source('./utility/cytoscape_util.R')

# Convert it into Cytosccape.js JSON
cygraph <- toCytoscape(g.tca)

send2cy(cygraph, 'default%20black', 'circular')

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Called from: file(con, "r")
```

But I didn't find error when I use "send2cy" function from terminal R (Run R from terminal just calling by "R").

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script with local copies of the network data and utility script, and with updated file paths. The script ran fine for me in R Studio.

Given the error message you are seeing "Error in file..." I suspect the issue is with your local files and file paths... somehow in an R Studio-specific way?

FYI: an updated, consolidated and update set of R scripts for Cytoscape are available here: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-automation/tree/master/for-scripters/R.  I don't think anything has significantly changed, but perhaps trying in a new context will resolve the issue you are facing.